# Creating a linux virtual machine from disk in azure using python

Tags: python, linux, amazon-web-services, azure

I want to create a Linux virtual machine from a disk in azure using python. I found some links where it was suggested to do something with `VHD`, but it was not clearly explained how to do that.
Can anyone explain the answer using python (not on `CLI` or `powershell` or in `JSON`).

I have referred this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/python) :

```
VM_PARAMETERS = {

            'location': LOCATION,
            'os_profile': {
                'computer_name': VM_NAME,
                'admin_username': USERNAME,
                'admin_password': PASSWORD
            },
            'hardware_profile': {
                'vm_size': 'Basic_A0'
            },
            'storage_profile': {
                'image_reference': {
                    'publisher': 'Canonical',
                    'offer': 'UbuntuServer',
                    'sku': '16.04.0-LTS',
                    'version': 'latest'
                },
            },
            'network_profile': {
                'network_interfaces': [{
                    'id': nic_id,
                }]
            },

}

compute_client.virtual_machines.create_or_update(GROUP_NAME, VM_NAME, VM_PARAMETERS)
```

Please help me with this.

Comment: In fact, the VM_parameters like a json file. You could check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/using-managed-disks-template-deployments#unmanaged-disks-template-formatting).

Comment: I removed the powershell tag.  If.in error just add back.

Answer (score 0):

You specifically ask...

> Can anyone explain the answer using python ***(not on CLI or powershell or in JSON)***.

Yet, you are asking the question in PowerShell Q&A forum.

Should you not be then asking the question on the python forums?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python

All that being said. A VHD is a virtual hard disk. You have to have one, in place first, to attach to a VM, in order to spin up a virtual machine.

> How to create an Azure VM with the azurerm Python library
>
> There are at least two ways to work with Azure infrastructure using
>   Python. You can use the official Azure SDK for Python which supports
>   all Azure functionality, or the azurerm REST wrapper library, which is
>   unofficial and supports a subset of the Azure REST API.
>
> https://msftstack.wordpress.com/2016/08/05/how-to-create-an-azure-vm-with-the-azurerm-python-library

Comment: I refereed the github link, but there is nothing related to the question. There is all other things like creating VM from image and attaching an extra disk. But I want to create a VM from disk. Can you tell me the procedure ?